# Spit data to the select field from the database

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlN7J.jpg)I am new to coding. I just started building a website and I am currently working on the profile page. I wanted the input fields to be populated by the information the user has provided (see attached picture). This I have achieved.

My problem now is... I can't spit information from the database to the select tag.

For the other input fields, I just had to echo the data spooled from the database as seen in my HTML below:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 white-bg">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>
                                <span class="text-left">FIRST NAME</span>
                                <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>" disabled>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>
                                <span class="text-left">LAST NAME</span>
                                <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $last_name ?>" disabled>
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>
                                <span class="text-left">GENDER</span>
                                <select name="gender">
                                    <option value="" disabled hidden selected>--Select--</option>
                                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="Others">Others</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>
                                <span class="text-left">DATE OF BIRTH</span>
                                <input type="DATE" name="dob" value="<?php echo $dob ?>">
                            </label>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But I can't do the same for the **select** tag. How do I have an option selected based on the information the user has provided such that the **Male** option is selected if the user entered **male** or the the **Female** option is selected if the user entered **Female**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the keyword based on the value returned from your DB.

So in your code add something like

-- For your default select option do

```
<?php echo(empty($theGender)?" selected":""); ?>
```

-- For Male/Female do, checking for value you stored

```
<option value="Female"<?php echo(($theGender === "female")?" selected":""); ?> >Female</option>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SmileIT, it worked like magic. But I am not ashamed to admit that I do not quite follow through. Let me explain, if I am wrong, please put me right. What you did is like an **If** statement. PHP checks the value stored in the $gender and matches it with the values of the options in the **select** tag. If **true** it echoes **selected** and that option gets displayed in the **select** field. Am I right?